# How to strip slashes in Javascript (json)? Any JQuery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, stripslashes

So, when I save the data into database, PHP will add a \  on single or double quotes.  That is good.

**However, when data is passed back to the client using json_encode();  TEXT like McDonald's is STORED as McDonald's in the DB but once passed back from PHP to js, it will be encoded as McDonald\'s**

Since I'm using jQuery, is there any plugin to easily do that? or any function I should use to strip the slashes correctly?  obviously, if there is case like  `\\\\s`, the function should return `\s`.  :)

**Sorry guys. I think I made my question too complicated.  How about I make it simpler..**

If I have a javascript variable:

```
var abc = "McDonald\'s";
var bcd = "I need a slash \\ ";
var cde = "save the double quote \"";
```

how can I strip the \' ?  what the regex I should use?

Comment: I'm a little worried about a lot of the answers here. My PHP security knowledge is somewhat dated, so I'm not really qualified to give a good answer here, but it is vitally important that if you do turn off magic quotes, you replace it with a **better** escaping system. Your goals should be to prevent both SQL injection and cross-site scripting attacks. I normally would use `mysql_real_escape_string($user_input)` going into the DB and `htmlentities($db_output)` going out to the client -- but this may not be considered 100% safe any more. Hopefully someone can give better advice.

Comment: What are you using in your JS to parse the JSON? Whatever you use whould de-escape everything, if it's generated properly (which `json_encode` will do).

Comment: @Andrew That advice is still sound, though generally you want to encode to a view with `htmlspecialchars()`. It is sufficient.

Comment: Hi @alex. This is a can of worms I'm not qualified to open, but my preference in the past was to go with `htmlentities()` because it is significantly more destructive to user input, without having any visible impact on the rendered page (as long as you match the page encoding). When I did some studying of hacking methods three years ago, I was appalled at the variety of unicode characters available to a determined hacker -- and I still don't understand how many of these techniques worked. And I'm still not 100% sure `htmlentities()` is safe, but I know it's safer than `htmlspecialchars()`.

Comment: @Andrew Well `htmlspecialchars()` targets just the characters generally used for XSS. I think using `htmlentities()` will do the same, but just bloat the page using `&#xx;` style encoding for exotic characters, and most encoded stuff can be achieved by using UTF-8 as the character set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use: http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php before storing into database.

Use a custom function like this before writing onto any user interface:

```
function unescape($string)
{

$search = array("\\x00", "\\n", "\\r", "\\\x1a");

$replace = array("\x00","\n", "\r", "\x1a");

$retString = str_replace($search, $replace, $string);

$search = array("\'", '\\'.'"');

$replace = array(  "'", '"',);

$retString = str_replace($search, $replace, $retString);

$search = array("\\\\");

$replace = array( "\\");

$retString = str_replace($search, $replace, $retString);

return $retString

}
```

Comment: Better than mine.. lol     i have a new function that have \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

Answer (score 8):

It's actually [highly discouraged to use this "magic quotes" feature](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) that inserts slashes. In general, you never want to store data in the database in an escaped format; you want to do the escaping and encoding in the output.

Comment: Actually, I just check the DB, the magic quote is off.  It will store McDonald's in DB.  HOWEVER, the data generated from json_encode will attach the \'.  That has to like that when getting back to JSON.  BUT how can I remove the strip in JS?

Comment: That's not *quite* correct; you want to escape data where it leaves the application in a way appropriate to where it's going. That is, you escape it for SQL generation in a way that doesn't store it escaped.

Comment: @seatoskyhk, as @alex explains in his answer, use a JSON parser in JavaScript.

Answer (score 4):

I would take care of the main problem - `magic_quotes` is enabled.

I would [disable it](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php) and use proper escaping methods with your database.

Then you don't have to worry about PHP *magically* adding slashes.

If you are talking about slashes when using `json_encode()`, it does that for a reason.

Use a [JSON parser](http://www.json.org/js.html) in JavaScript and you won't see them (unless something else is improperly encoding them).

Comment: For the JSON part, that exactly I need to figure out..  I don't want to have \' when I extract the data.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
http://phpjs.org/functions/stripslashes:537

Comment: I read that already. but it is so messy that other people's comment provide different things and saying it doesn't work in IE...

Comment: That one doesn't work. .return error... unmatched ) in regular expression

Answer (score 1):

Try this too

```
function stripslashes (str) {

  return (str + '').replace(/\\(.?)/g, function (s, n1) {
    switch (n1) {
    case '\\':
      return '\\';
    case '0':
      return '\u0000';
    case '':
      return '';
    default:
      return n1;
    }
  });
}
```